# What is the shortest syntax of zen coding/ emmet for writing following html?

Tags: emmet

What is the shortest syntax of zen coding/ emmet  for writing following html?

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use following.

```
div#main-wrapper>(div#left>div.inner-wrapper>div.wrapper)+(div#right>div.inner-wrapper>div.wrapper)
```

I got result but I have to repeat the same inner content in both column. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip `div`:

```
#main-wrapper>(#left>.inner-wrapper>.wrapper)+(#right>.inner-wrapper>.wrapper)
```

Or, you can write

```
#main-wrapper>#*2>.inner-wrapper>.wrapper
```

...then traverse with Tab key (if your editor supports tab stops) or use [Go to Edit Point](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/go-to-edit-point/) action to move to generated empty `id` attributes and fill values.